# Str_replace doesn't work

Tags: php

I want to write some code which imports a CSV file, takes the useful bits, and then puts it into a database. For now I have written the code which just outputs it into a table, so that I can check all my values are working. So Far so good! However I am unhappy with how one of the fields from my CSV file is appearing. I would like to edit it. At the moment the field appears something like this:

**Mode: 5; Speed: mSpeed Speed; Tilt Range: Full**

I want to strip off everything except the mode. To do that I am using

```
list($mode) = explode(";", $fixture_options);
```

This outputs:

**Mode: 5**

So far So good! The next step is to get rid of the 'Mode:' I was hoping to simply use:

```
$newmode = str_replace("Mode:","", $mode);
```

But this doesn't seem to work? This is my full code below. No doubt it's something simple!

```
  <?php

    function Table($name,$value)
        {
            echo "<tr><td>$name</td><td>$value</td></tr>";
        }



ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings', TRUE);
$rows = array_map('str_getcsv', file('test.csv'));
$header = array_shift($rows); // Strip out the colum headers from the CSV
$csv = array();
foreach ($rows as $row) {


    /*** Remove all the unwanted Colums **/

            unset($row[2]); // Remove Dimmer
            unset($row[6]); // Remove Lens
            unset($row[7]); // Remove Hookup
            unset($row[8]); // Remove Purpose
            unset($row[9]); // Remove Colour
            unset($row[10]); // Remove Gobo
            unset($row[11]); // Remove Focus
            unset($row[16]); // Remove Lamp Type
            unset($row[17]); // Remove Offset
            unset($row[18]); // Remove X
            unset($row[19]); // Remove Y
            unset($row[20]); // Remove Z
            unset($row[21]); // Remove Pan
            unset($row[22]); // Remove Tilt
            unset($row[23]); // Remove Spin
            unset($row[25]); // Remove Notes
            unset($row[26]); // Remove Footnotes
            unset($row[28]); // Remove # of colour frames
            unset($row[29]); // Remove # of lamps
            unset($row[30]); // Remove Circuit Type
            unset($row[31]); // Remove Model        
            unset($row[32]); // Remove Cost
            unset($row[34]); // Remove Console
            unset($row[35]); // Remove Layer
            unset($row[36]); // Remove Tag

        $channel =          $row[0];
        $patch =            $row[1];
        list($uni, $address) = explode(".", $patch); // we convert the address into univers and address.
        $spot =             $row[3];
        $position =         $row[4];
        $type =             $row[5];
        $circuit_name =     $row[12];
        $circuit_number =   $row[13];
        $fixture_options =  $row[14];

        list($mode) = explode(";", $fixture_options); // We strip the other mode options out
        $newmode = str_replace("Mode:","", $mode); 

        $wattage =          $row[15];
        $weight =           $row[24];
        $status =           $row[33];



echo "<table>";
Table('Channel',$channel);
Table('Universe',$uni);
Table('Address',$address);
Table('Spot',$spot);
Table('Position',$position);
Table('Type',$type);
Table('Circuit Name',$circuit_name);
Table('Circuit Number',$circuit_number);
Table('Fixture Mode',$newmode);
Table('Wattage',$wattage);
Table('Weight',$weight);
Table('Status',$status);

echo "</table>";


}
```

Comment: Show a var_dump() of `$mode`

Comment: If `str_replace` doesn't replace a string that means that exact string is not in your string. If `var_dump` is still leaving doubts, use `echo bin2hex($mode)` and compare it with `echo bin2hex('Mode:')`.

Answer (score 3):

My advice: Take it using a regexp in one go:

```
$string = "Mode: 5; Speed: mSpeed Speed; Tilt Range: Full";

preg_match('/Mode: (\d+);/',$string, $matches);

//result in $matches[1];
```